# S4 classes - overload a method with a variable number of arguments

Tags: r, generics, overloading, r-s4, arity

I would like to have a variable number of arguments in my S4 generic `myMethod` such that these are both valid:

```
myMethod(100)
myMethod(100, 200)
```

Here is my attempt at a definition:

```
setGeneric(
    "myMethod", 
    function(x) {

        standardGeneric("myMethod")
    })

setMethod(
    "myMethod", 
    signature = c("numeric"), 
    definition = function(x) {

        print("MyMethod on numeric")
    })

setMethod(
    "myMethod", 
    signature = c("numeric", "numeric"), 
    definition = function(x, y) {

        print("MyMethod on numeric, numeric")
    })
```

However, this gives the error:

> Error in matchSignature(signature, fdef) : 
>     more elements in the method signature (2) than in the generic signature (1) for function ‘myMethod’

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your generic should support 2 arguments.

```
setGeneric(
  "myMethod", 
  function(x, y) {
    standardGeneric("myMethod")
  })
```

Also the function in your second method should actually support two arguments:

```
setMethod(
  "myMethod", 
  signature = c("numeric", "numeric"), 
  definition = function(x, y) {
    print("MyMethod on numeric, numeric")
  })
```

More generally, if you want to specify arbitrarily many arguments, you should have a look at the elipsis argument `...`.

Comment: Ah the second point was a typo on my part. This works, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It's worth clarifying whether you want to *dispatch* (select a method) on more than one argument (in which case include all argument names in the `signature=` of `setGeneric()`)

```
setGeneric("fun", function(x, y) standardGeneric("fun"),
           signature=c("x", "y"))

setMethod("fun", c(x="numeric", y="numeric"), function(x, y) {
    "fun,numeric,numeric-method"
})
```

versus dispatching based on the first (include only the first argument  in `signature=`) and either require all methods to have additional arguments (name the arguments in the generic function)

```
setGeneric("fun", function(x, y) standardGeneric("fun"),
           signature="x")

setMethod("fun", c(x="numeric"), function(x, y) {
    "fun,numeric-method"
})
```

or only some methods (use `...` in the generic, and name the arguments in the method).

```
setGeneric("fun", function(x, ...) standardGeneric("fun"),
           signature="x")

setMethod("fun", c(x="numeric"), function(x, y) {
    "fun,numeric-method"
})
```